# How to slice and sum the N-d tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape [None,2,7], a dummy shape for better understanding. I need to get the below numpy functionality in tensorflow.

```
arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7], [4, 5, 6,1,2,3,4]], [[1, 2, 3,7,6,5,4], [4, 5, 6,4,3,2,1]]])

#in numpy 
x[:, :, -3:] = x[:, :, :3] - \
    x[:, :, :3].sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)/num         #num shape is [None,1,1]
```

I need to do the above operation in tensorflow. But tensorflow does not support slicing operation on placeholders.

In my case x's None is depending upon other operations. If it is input placeholder, It would have been easy.

Any workaround or help for this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the operation that you need and concatenate with the rest of old tensor.

```
sliced = x[:, :, :3] - tf.reduce_sum(x[:, :, :3], axis=1, keepdims=True) 
new_tensor = tf.concat([x[:,:,:-3], sliced], axis=-1)
```

If you need the same name afterwards just

```
old_tensor = new_tensor
```